# How to remove now ignored files from SVN

Tags: shell, svn

By accident somebody commited cache files to SVN (svnignore was wrong)

I updated the SVN ignore and want now to remove all the currently ignored files from the SVN (local copies should be kept).

How do to that?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove the ignored items in the repository first and ask the users to run `svn update` as they always do. The items will be removed in the user's working copies and this should be completely OK just because every user at the moment should be seeing constant conflict errors, especially when he rebuilds the project.

Once you remove the cache files, they will be ignored in the working copies and no one will commit them by mistake anymore.

Comment: Thank you. Concerning: "You will have to remove the ignored items in the repository first" is there an easy to use one-liner for this?

Comment: Sure, but how for all those ignored files at once?